# Magento: How to add .html extension on custom module Front Name?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a custom extension, My module XML files is as follow:

```
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <articlepagination>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Test_Articlepagination</module>
            <frontName>test-landing</frontName>
          </args>
      </articlepagination>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <articlepagination>
              <file>articlepagination.xml</file>
            </articlepagination>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
```

When I run URL with frontname "test-landing" it works (www.xyz.com/test-landing) but i want my url to work with .html extension (www.xyz.com/test-landing.html)

How can it be done (without any htacess redirect) ?

To make it work,I tried to change the Frontname as   `<frontName>test-landing.html</frontName>` and the www.xyz.com/test-landing.html worked, Is it correct way to do so ? I don't think its correct way.

Thanks.